# python, dict deep keys replace

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict like

```
{'1': {'b': 1, 'c': 2}, '2': {'b': 3, 't': 4}, '3': {'b': 1, 'z': 1}}
```

and I need to replace all 'b' keys with, for example, 'bb' (and get a new dict). The output should be

```
{'1': {'bb': 1, 'c': 2}, '2': {'bb': 3, 't': 4}, '3': {'bb': 1, 'z': 1}}
```

Is there any easy-pythonic way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want to keep the old dict?

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
In [3]: for k, v in d.items():
   ...:     d[k]['bb'] = v.pop('b')
   ...:     

In [4]: d
Out[4]: {'2': {'t': 4, 'bb': 3}, '3': {'z': 1, 'bb': 1}, '1': {'bb': 1, 'c': 2}}
```

The above code causes `KeyError` if some of the nested dictionaries don't have `'b'` key. Fail-safe version:

```
In [8]: for k, v in d.items():
   ...:     if 'b' in v:
   ...:         d[k]['bb'] = v.pop('b')
```

The above solution will make changes to the **original** dictionary. You can make its copy with [`copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) (like Padraic Cunningham suggested in comments).

One-liner (dictionary comprehension creates a **new** `dict` object):

```
In [13]: { x: dict(('bb' if y == 'b' else y, d[x][y]) for y in d[x]) for x in d }
Out[13]: {'2': {'t': 4, 'bb': 3}, '3': {'z': 1, 'bb': 1}, '1': {'bb': 1, 'c': 2}}
```

Comment: @wim not quite sure what did OP mean by that.

Comment: if you used d_copy= copy.deepcopy(d) and updated a new dict you could keep the old and new dict.

Comment: @frostnational, no worries.